# Multihomed Cisco VPN server

Tags: vpn, cisco

I am trying to configure Cisco 1841 with two external IPs to accept VPN connections on either external interface and maintain data flow through the interface on which VPN connection did happen.

My Cisco has two external links: one is slow but unlimited and cheap, second is fast but has monthly data allowance. Idea is that I would like to configure VPN clients with one or another external VPN host address in order to select which link is in use.

I have the following config:

```
crypto isakmp client configuration group vpnclients
 key secretkey
 dns 172.16.64.1
 domain domain.com
 pool vpnpool

crypto isakmp profile VPNclient
   description VPN clients profile
   match identity group vpnclients
   client authentication list clientauth
   isakmp authorization list groupauthor
   client configuration address respond

crypto ipsec transform-set myset esp-3des esp-sha-hmac

crypto dynamic-map dynmap 5
 set transform-set myset
 set isakmp-profile VPNclient
 reverse-route

crypto map mymap 10 ipsec-isakmp dynamic dynmap

interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 123.33.90.97 255.255.255.248
 crypto map mymap

interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 193.41.235.251 255.255.255.248
 crypto map mymap

ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 FastEthernet0/0
```

The problem I have, I believe, is in default ip route which forces all returning traffic to go through Fa0/0 . I cannot figure out how to force VPN traffic out through Fa0/1 if VPN connection happened on 193.41.235.251.

What would be the best way to resolve the issue? Policy routing?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using cryto maps to encrypt specific traffic, the external vrf option is probably not going to work.

One other option would be to use policy-routing like you suggested, but since you are trying to policy route packets generated by the box, you need to use the `ip local policy` syntax.

This is an example, it might work but I don't know the IOS version or feature-set, and have no insight into the rest of the configuration on the router.

```
ip access-list extended F01-VPN-SOURCE-ACL
 permit ip host 193.41.235.251 any

route-map F01-VPN-MAP 10
 match ip address F01-VPN-SOURCE-ACL
 set interface fa0/1
 set ip next-hop 193.41.235.###

ip local policy route-map F01-VPN-MAP
```

Comment: Do you mind to provide an example?

Comment: Looking at your config further it looks like you're only encrypting certain traffic with the crypto map... the external vrf/vrf-aware VPN would only work for a dedicated VPN device.  I've updated the answer with a possible solution for your use.